# Issue using Sikuli Pattern on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver, sikuli

I am trying to perform a small calculation as part of my selenium learning with Java, Sikuli using Eclipse IDE.
**My Code is as below:**

```
package webelements.concepts;

import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.ImagePath;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
```

public class DeskTopIconEx {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed, InterruptedException {
    // to Perform small calculation on Calculator app which is present on screen.

    ImagePath.setBundlePath("/Users/murthyinguva/Desktop/Images");

    Thread.sleep(4000);
    Screen screenObj = new Screen();

    Pattern btnCObj = new Pattern("//Users//murthyinguva//Desktop//Images//btnC");
    Pattern btn9Obj = new Pattern("//Users//murthyinguva//Desktop//Images//btn9");
    Pattern btnXObj = new Pattern("//Users//murthyinguva//Desktop//Images//btnX");
    Pattern btn5Obj = new Pattern("//Users//murthyinguva//Desktop//Images//btn5");
    Pattern btnEqualsObj = new Pattern("//Users//murthyinguva//Desktop//Images//btnEquals");
    String paths = ImagePath.getBundlePath();
    System.out.println("Image path given as :" + paths);

        screenObj.click(btnCObj);
        screenObj.click(btn9Obj);
        screenObj.click(btnXObj);
        screenObj.click(btn5Obj);
        screenObj.click(btnEqualsObj);
}
```

}

**Console output is:**

`Image path given as :/Users/murthyinguva/Desktop/Images
Exception in thread "main" FindFailed: btnC.png: (90x88) in R[0,0 1440x900]@S(0)
Line 2226, in file Region.java

```
at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2226)
at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2244)
at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3298)
at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3916)
at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3892)
at webelements.concepts.DeskTopIconEx.main(DeskTopIconEx.java:25)
```

`

Help required:

I would like to know your advises why i am getting this error and unable to see that Sikuli is performing any mouse actions. I have given the permissions as per:

`https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/wiki/Allow-SikuliX-actions-on-macOS`

Because of this difficulty I am unable to progress much, Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[Desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK9gB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The forward slashes in the filenames have to be single.

But since you have used

```
setBundlePath()
```

before, the Patterns can be reduced to

```
String btnCObj = "btnC";
```

All the best. RaiMan from SikuliX.

Comment: Thanks RaiMan for your reply. Still I am facing issue even after following your suggestions.